# Difference bettween ubuntu xenial, yakkety and zesty

Tags: ubuntu, version

What is the difference between ubuntu Xenial, Yakkety and Zesty. I am trying to install a ubuntu OS using root server of a cloud system. I dont know which one to install?

And if possible please tell me the command to install. The software is in tar.gz format.

[image]

Comment: They're different Ubuntu versions. You probably want the LTS (Long Term Stable). http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu uses version names alongside the numbers.

- 16.04 Xenial
- 16.10 Yakety
- 17.04 Zesty

They also happen to be in alphabetical order. The release number represents the release date in format YY.MM, meaning that Ubuntu makes a proper release each 6 months.

The latest Long-Term Support (LTS) version is 16.04 so you could use that if you require stability.

Otherwise, newer is better.

Comment: @Herald - Sorry for the delay. I just accepted the answer. Thanks a lot for your help